# R sf aggregate (unite) polygons at various geographic levels (columns) within a dataframe

Tags: r, r-sf

I'm trying to aggregate polygons at different geographic levels. As a hypothetical and reproducible example, let's suppose that I want to aggregate US county data set at the state level (of course, I can directly retrieve state-level polygons if this was my "actual" problem).

I've tried to do it by applying st_union for each group, where the group is each state. The code seems to work fine, but when I try to use it for plotting or other data manipulation, R throws an error message as below.

In general, if we have multiple levels of geography within a data (e.g., state, county, city, zip code, etc) and if we want to aggregate it at different levels, what's the best approach?

```
counties <- USAboundaries::us_counties() 

state_union <- counties %>% 
  group_by(state_abbr) %>%
  summarise(geometry = sf::st_union(geometry)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% st_as_sf()

plot(st_geometry(state_union))
Error in CPL_geos_is_empty(st_geometry(x)) : Not a matrix.
```

Any comments would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you check out the discussion [here](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/131), you can see there is an issue with using `st_union` within a `summarize()` call. However, `{sf}` has its own `summarize.sf()` method that will automatically aggregate the geometries by group:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.7.2, GDAL 2.4.2, PROJ 5.2.0

counties <- USAboundaries::us_counties() 

counties %>% 
  group_by(state_abbr) %>% 
  summarize() %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  plot()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>